# ATTACH DATABASE on sqlite in Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I'm new to xamarin. I'm trying to convert an existing iOS app. This app uses multiple sqlite files and uses the "attach database" feature in sqlite so we can access and join data in multiple files. 
Is there a library that supports this. I've tried a couple of the sqlite libraries and the "attach database" statement will execute but when I try to select data in the db that I attached, it says that table doesn't exist.

Here's some code. The select statement gets an error about the table not existing. I know my path is correct and my table exists because I can connect directly to the second db and run a select. I've tried using transactions also. No luck.

```
SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection(fileInfo.DirectoryName + "one", null, true);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format(@"ATTACH DATABASE '{0}' as DBTWO",Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, "two")));
db.ExecuteNonQuery(@"select * from DBTWO.tabletwo");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://medium.com/@patibrijesh/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2c6ec5894510